# How to properly retrieve data from Cloud Firestore using Flutter and Future Builder?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-futurebuilder

I am new to Flutter and especially Cloud Firestore. My data is stored as a Map containing another Map in my collection. To keep queries to my database as low as possible, I will store the data in a single document and want to retrieve only the lastest document. The code regarding fetching the data:

```
Future<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> fetchData() async {
  final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  late Map<dynamic, dynamic> data;

  try {
    await _firestore
        .collection('collection')
        .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
        .limit(1)
        .get()
        .then((value) => data = value.docs.first.data());
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
  return data;
}
```

Firstly, I am wondering whether there is a better way to getting the stored map from the most recent document in my collection?

Secondly,I would like to wait for this to finish and then use a FutureBuilder to show each element of my map as text, for example. At a later stage I was thinking about using a provider called in the initState that can send the data retrieved to various screens. For now, I am simply trying to display the data, but it seems like I am misunderstanding how this works:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  late Future<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> fixtures;

  @override
  void initState() {
    fixtures = _getData();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> _getData() async {
    return await fetchData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
          future: fixtures,
          builder: (BuildContext context,
              AsyncSnapshot<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(child: Text('loading...'));
            } else {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
              } else {
                return Center(child: Text('${snapshot.data!['XY']}'));
              }
            }
          }),
    ));
  }
}
```

It kind of works this way, but I feel like its not correct. What I don't really understand is how to properly access the data from the snapshot, how to properly store all data, and if there is a better way of doing so. The documentation always simply says snapshot.data but does not actually use the data retrieved to perform any action.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks fine to me, if maybe a bit convoluted.

I'd probably simplify your `fetchData` to:

```
Future<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> fetchData() async {
  var value = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('collection')
        .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
        .limit(1)
        .get()
  return value.docs.first.data();
}
```

The changes:

- Removed the `catch`. Since you're not really handling the error, it's best to let it bubble up and only catch errors at the top-level, where you can then centrally log them or for example send them to Crashlytics.
- It's often harder to read code that combines `await` and `then.` Use one of the other.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! Is there a better way of dealing with the snapshot in the FutureBuilder? I didnt find any good documentation explaining how to access the data with respect to null safety. I have seen examples where they simply say snapshot.data.someValue, but it does not allow me to do that in the FutureBuilder...

Comment: If you're having trouble with the simplified code and a `FutureBuilder`, I recommend posting a new question with the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as well as the exact error message and stack trace you get.